# Customize dynamic URL.change ?id to name

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I'm using codeigniter for make dynamic website. In news page, I use url method like: `http://test.com/test/test/news_details?id=27`

how can i change my url to put news title within `?id=27`

example:

```
http://test.com/test/test/news_details/pass-this-url
```

"pass-this-url" refer to id=27.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Use routes : http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

In your case it will be something like this :

```
$route['pass-this-url'] = "test/test/news_details?id=27";
```

So http://www.example.com/pass-this-url will be understand by codeigniter as http://www.example.com/test/test/news_details?id=27

however, if you want to make it dynamic, you will have to call your db :

```
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get( 'news' );
$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row )
{
    $route[$row->title] = "test/test/news_details?id=". $row->id;
    //We suppose here that your title is URL friendly.
}
```

Comment: tnx for your answer but , when i use dynamic method , and print all route , no route will be added. and static route don't do anything and redirect me to 404 page :(

Comment: What you mean by "print all routes" ?

Comment: i use 'print_r($this -> router -> routes);' to see my route that added with function.

Comment: Then you should check if the query returns any result.

Comment: my query return result. but still route don't add any thing.

Comment: can u see it your self plz?

Answer (score 0):

Go to application/config/config.php and check this:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: i checked this, but no change. :)