# How to change blog-id to blog-title in the URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I am trying to change my web template url from `../blog/read/1` to `../blog/read/title-of-blog` to be more user friendly.
I've been searching and found this thread [Customize dynamic URL.change ?id to name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537819/customize-dynamic-url-change-id-to-name)
 but I don't know what the best way is to handle this problem. I came up with two solutions.

**1. Change function blog/read/id to blog/read/title-of-blog**

But this feels like it's going to bring problems because what if two blogs have the same name?

**2. Routes** (code from thread linked above)

Use database to update routes.php so every blog has it's own route. This would look like this in routes.php

```
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get( 'blog' );
$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row )
{
    $route[$row->title] = "blog/read/". $row->id;
    //We suppose here that your title is URL friendly.
}
```

This code does not work for my version, I cannot get my database to load in routes.php

```
Error: require_once(/home/x/public_html/system/database/DBEXT): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with `SESSION`. It is required for selection of blog You can Use the title of the blog in URL only for user-friendly no for selection of blog. so you can send id of the blog with `SESSION`. no need to edit `routes.php` file.